# Cant sign into any Google iOS app

Tags: google, google-maps, iphone

Cannot sign into any Google iOS app (Google, Google Maps, Google Earth) on my new iPhone 7 Plus.

It says:
"Sorry there seems to be a problem please try again"

Have tried:
-Resetting iPhone
-Signing into the accounts on my iPhone 6 (Works fine)
-Signing in to a different account on iphone 7 (Doesnt work)
-Uninstalling and reinstalling the apps
-Enabling 2 factor authentication

But still no fix

Logging into the account on the computer works fine as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try signing in on Safari. Does that work?

Comment: If I try to log into google with Safari.app it lets me do that. If I use the Google.app and hit the safari button in the lower right hand corner when trying to sign in I get the same "Sorry there seems to be a problem please try again".

Comment: Googling the issue, are you going away from the login screen any time during the login process, perhaps to a password manager? That might be causing it

Comment: When you uninstalled the apps did you do a hard reset (sleep + volume down until the Apple logo appears) before reinstalling them? If not, they are still using the same data, as that data is not deleted until the device is hard reset or the space is needed. If there's some corruption in the data causing this, uninstalling and reinstalling without doing a hard reset in between would result in the same corrupted data being used again.

Comment: Hi Skeleton Bow, nope not going to a password manager at

Comment: tubedogg - will try that and report back. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Download the Google Chrome app on the iPhone and sign in to your Google account in the Chrome app.  Then open the Gmail app (or any other Google app) and you should have an option to slide a switch and be logged in to your account in the Gmail app as well.  if you don't get that option try deleting and re downloading the Gmail app.

Problem seems to be between Safari and the Google login, in my case with two-factor enabled.